# A Simulator for a non-deterministic Push-Down Automaton

Tags: java

Well, I need to make simulator for non-deterministic Push-Down Automaton.
Everything is okey, I know I need to do recursion or something similar. But I do not know how to make that function which would simulate automaton.

I got everything else under control, automaton generator, stack ...
I am doing it in java, so this is maybe only issue that man can bump on, and I did it.
So if anyone have done something similar, I could use advices.

This is my current organisation of code:

```
Classes:  class transit:
  list<transit> -contains non deterministic transitions
  state
  input  sign
  stack sign class generator
  it generate automaton from file clas NPA
  public boolean start() - this function I am having trouble with
```

Of course problem of separate stacks, and input for every branch.

I tried to solve it with collection of objects NPA and try to start every object, but it doesn work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, think about the definition of the automaton.  You have states and a state transition function. You have the stack.  What makes life exciting is the non-determinism.

however, it is a theorem (look it up) that every nondeterministic finite automaton has an equivalent deterministic FSA.

One approach you could try is to construct the equivalent DFA.  That's exponential space in the worst case, though: every state in the DFA maps to a subset of the powerset of the NFA states.

So you could try it "on line" instead.  Now, instead of constructing the equivalent DFA, you simulate the NFA; at state transitions you construct all the next states you reach and put them on some data structure; then go back and see what happens next for each such state.

Comment: Wasn't the question about *push-down* automata?

Comment: Sure.  And what's the definition of a push-down automaton?  A stack with a finite state controller.  So you do a nondeterministic PDA as a stack with a nondeterministic finite state controller.  Solve the problem of simulating an NFA and you've got NPDA and NTM solved.

Comment: I know this question is old, but for those reading this in the future, converting the NFA controller to an equivalent DFA doesn't work, even in exponential space. The state of the stack itself is nondeterministic, so whatever equivalent DFA you end up with would have to be able to handle an arbitrarily large number of possible stacks. In fact, PDA's are not equivalent to DPDA's: the former can simulate any context-free language, but the latter can only simulate deterministic context-free languages, which form a proper subset. The solution in the last paragraph is still correct though.

Comment: @EvanBailey Rabin and Scott are going to be very surprised. https://www.bookofproofs.org/branches/reduction-of-nfa-to-dfa-rabin-scott-theorem/ The trick with the tape is that it simulates nondeterminism by constructing a new alphabet that's the powerset of the original alphabet.

Comment: @CharlieMartin Sorry if my comment was unclear. I didn't mean to imply that you can't convert an NFA to a DFA; I was saying that can't be used to convert a PDA to a DPDA. As you say, the trick for converting an NFA to a DFA is to treat the set of possible states in the NFA as a single state in the DFA. If there are n states in the DFA, there are 2^n subsets of those n states, so at most 2^n DFA states are necessary.

The problem is that when you introduce a stack, the number of states is no longer bounded, so there is no nice way to convert a nondeterministic to a deterministic automaton.

Answer (score 0):

[JFLAP](http://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/jflap/tutorial/) is open source and does this (and much more!) - why not check it out?